# Database Backup best practices

Tags: database, backup, restore, marklogic

I am working in a production environment, where we process `XML` files daily. Our database size is quite big. we are taking a daily backup. I learned that `Marklogic` adds up changes to your previous backup to create new backup.

I wanted to confirm that is it the best way to keep daily backup or there is any other better way to do it. Also is there any limit to the process, that I am following. My Database size is around **350 GB** and increasing daily. So I am looking for a faster and easier solution.

Answer (score 3):

This question is fairly open-ended: there is no single "best way". MarkLogic supports full online backups, and journal archiving for continuous incremental backup. The docs at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore discuss these options.

Instead of a full daily backup, you might consider a full weekly backup plus journal archiving. As you start a new week, you can do whatever you like with the data the from previous week: retain it, delete it, move it onto cheaper storage, etc.

As MarkLogic databases go, 350-GB is not so large. However at that point you should have already configured multiple forests: see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/scalability#id_96443 for guidelines. Assuming you have multiple CPU cores, storing the content in a proportional number of forests will improve performance throughout the system. That includes backup, because multiple forests will back up in parallel - though of course the disk may still be the bottleneck. If storage is the bottleneck, separating the I/O for forests and backup is advisable.

If having multiple forests is a new idea, you might also be interested in https://github.com/mblakele/task-rebalancer